# ERROR: integer expression expected - comparing tables

Tags: bash, ascii

I have a small bash program, that allows me to compare tables (having similar naming style) and that copies to another directory the file having the highest value at the first row of the fourth column (with space separator) (the values of the fourth column are decimal numbers e.g. 1111.22).

```
#! /bin/bash
river=lobith_rhine
highest=1
for model in H08
do
  for gcm in IPSL-CM5A-LR
  do
    for scenario in hist rcp8p5
    do
      for x in ${model}_${gcm}_${scenario}_${river}[1-9]/${model}_${gcm}_${scenario}_${river}[1-9].txt
      do
        fourth="$(awk 'NR==1{print $4}' $x)"
        if [ "$highest" -lt "$fourth" ];then
            highest=$fourth
            hifile=$x
        fi
      done
      echo "highest was $highest in $hifile"
      cp $hifile /home/steve/high_test/${model}_${gcm}_${scenario}_${river}.txt
    done
  done
done
```

Unfortunately, the line 13 `if [ "$highest" -lt "$fourth" ];then` produces the following error message:

```
integer expression expected
```

So, I read some documentation about comparisons operators, and found that I can replace the problematic line by

```
if [ "$highest" \< "$fourth" ];then
```

But this is not working properly since it just compares the ascii alphabetic order values rather than the entire value.

Does anyone has an idea about how to handle those issues?

Comment: Since you're using `awk` to extract the value, why not use it to do the numeric comparison as well? With some re-work, you can probably replace the loop over files as well.

Comment: I suppose you have some "table" with the header in the first line... check it. `head -n 1 */*txt` or something similar.

Comment: @Hastur Unfortunately there is no header. I tried to used 'bc' but I didn´t succed to get the right output

Comment: There is even the internal `awk` solution (gawk)... Updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok that is a workaround that should work

```
#! /bin/bash
river=lobith_rhine
highest=1
for model in H08
do
  for gcm in IPSL-CM5A-LR
  do
    for scenario in hist rcp8p5
    do
      RESULT=$(awk 'FNR==1 {print $4, FILENAME}' ${model}_${gcm}_${scenario}_${river}[1-9]/${model}_${gcm}_${scenario}_${river}[1-9].txt | sort -n -r| head -1) 
      highest="$(echo $RESULT | cut -d ' ' -f1 )"
      hifile="$(echo $RESULT | cut -d ' ' -f2 )"
      echo "highest was $highest in $hifile"
      cp "$hifile" "/home/steve/high_test/${model}_${gcm}_${scenario}_${river}.txt"
    done
  done
done
```

The idea is inside the *awk* command over a bunch of files,

```
 awk 'FNR==1 {print $4, FILENAME}' *txt | sort -n -r| head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f2
```

where:

- [FNR](http://ss64.com/bash/awk.html) is the current file record number and [FILENAME](http://ss64.com/bash/awk.html) is the current file name
- `sort` is the [sort command](http://ss64.com/bash/sort.html)
- `cut` is the [cut command](http://ss64.com/bash/cut.html)

Ps> it's possible to think a solution without sort and head but only with awk.

```
awk 'FNR==1 {i++; A[i]=$4; B[i]=FILENAME} 
     END{ c=A[1];d=B[1];  
          for (j=2;j<i;j++){
            if (A[j]>c){c=A[j];d=B[j];}  
          } 
          print c,d ;
        }' *txt
```

Comment: It seems to work in finding the highest value. But something is wrong with the `cp` command `cp: invalid option -- '2'`. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: @steve To which version did you exactly refer?  Write an `echo` before the cp line ( `echo cp ......`) and you can read what it is wrong.

Comment: I refer to the first solution with `sort` and `cut`. What´s wrong is that there is no input file to copy, and I can´t figured out why!

Comment: My fault... I forgot the shell execution `$( )`. Updated  :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have `bc` available then you could replace line 13 with

```
if [ $(echo "$highest<$fourth" | bc) = 1 ];then
```